# Decimal place not working

Tags: java

Part of my code below show one of my methods  I want it to return a double with two decimals but it is saying price is a string why is this?

```
public Double calculate(double k, double m, int l, int n, double hr){
double price = 10.00;

 NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat.getNumberInstance();
    nf.setMaximumFractionDigits(2);
```

//Method in here

```
 return nf.format(price);
```

Comment: As an aside, price should be `BigDecimal` or `long` (representing cents), not `double`. Unless you don't care about the fact that you can't represent $0.10 correctly. See: http://floating-point-gui.de/

Comment: There is no such thing as a 'double with two decimals'. Floating point simply does not work that way. If you want a specific number of decimals, or decimal places, you have to work in a decimal radix.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It's saying price is a String because the `format` method returns a string.

Try something like this maybe,

`return Double.parseDouble(nf.format(price));`

Comment: However there is now no guarantee that the result contains two decimals, or decimal places.

Answer (score 2):

When you calculate a `double`, the way the computer stores it in memory does not account in any way for how you wish to display it. It is a value without any property.

By using `NumberFormat` you are creating code that takes the value stored in memory and manipulates it in such a way that is desired. Calling `nf.format()` returns a `String` which you can see [from the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/NumberFormat.html).

If you want to have a formatted number returned from the function you must set the return type to a `String`. If you still need to preserve the value of `price` you can return price and complete your formatting later in the code when it needs to be displayed.

Answer (score 1):

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/NumberFormat.html

That's what the method is supposed to do!

The prototype says it returns a string.

```
String format(double number); //Specialization of format.
```